# How to set the title in the middle of the page?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a title with a button on the right, but I met two problem:

- I want the title in the centre of the page;
- I want the button and title are in the same horizontal line.

This is my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="btn btn-primary pull-right">This is a long button</div>
    <h1 class="text-center">This is a long title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my [demo](https://codepen.io/huangjun/pen/eZrKNY).

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code to attain the desire result:

HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
  <div>
  <h1 class="col-xs-8 text-center">This is a long title</h1>
  </div> 
  <div class="btn btn-primary col-xs-2 pull-right mar">Follow</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mar{
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the tags **< center > < /center >**

**example:**

```
<a href="index.html" class="active"><center>long title</center></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this data in a new CSS file or in an existing CSS file.

```
#bt {
width: 100%;
}

.text-center {
width: 100%;
}
```

Also add an ID to the button as "bt".

Comment: This will make the button with full width. If you want it in the center, you can make a grid and make another grid inside that grid after giving some offset. That'll do the job. E.g. A grid of 6 columns with an offset of 3  inside a grid of 12 columns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I am thinking now, if it is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just zero the margin-top on the h1

```
.text-center {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

At least in your code-pen that did the trick.

In the future, in situations like this, always use the inspector on your browser to see the box-model of the element, helps a lot.
If you need more info on the box-model: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Answer (score 0):

Make Your Div Width as 100% and make use of Text-align Property.

```
<h2 style="text-align: center">XYZ</h2>
```

Then adjust your buttton with margin-top property.

Like this:-

```
 <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
   <div>
  <h1 class="col-xs-8 text-center" **style="margin-top: 0"**>This is a long title</h1>
     </div> 
   <div class="btn btn-primary col-xs-2 pull-right">Follow</div>

   </div>
  </div>
```